# MYSQL after update trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

I am new to database trigger. I really have no idea why i cant update the Label if the Quantity more than equal to 1000

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_UPDATE_STATUS
AFTER UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.QuantitySold >= 1000 THEN
    SET NEW.Label = 'BestSeller'
    END IF
  END
```

Here is the trigger I have.

Comment: Why don't you have any delimiter anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

You can only make persistent changes to `NEW` in a **`before row`** trigger. An **`after`** trigger doesn't fire until the record has already been written to the table.

To change the data *that will be written to the table,* you *must* use a **`before row`** trigger. Changing `NEW` in an **`after row`** trigger is possible, but pointless, since the contents of `NEW` get written to the table ***before*** an **`after`** trigger executes, as is explained [in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html).